# Upper bound on size of minimal binary coverage code

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory, error-correcting-codes, entropy, string-metrics

Let $1 \le r \le n$ b e integer(with $n$ large) and let $\mathscr X_n$ be the set set of all $2^n$ binary strings of length $n$. A binary $r$-coverage code is a subset $S$ of $\mathscr X_n$ such that every $x \in \mathscr X_n$ is within Hamming distance $\le r$ of some $y \in S$. A minimal $r$-coverage code is one for which the cardinality $|S|$ is minimal. Let this minimal cardinality be $N_n(r)$. Note that we have the trivial bound $N_n(r) \le 2^n$.

> **Question.** What are good upper-bounds for $N_n(r)$ in terms of $N$ and $r$ ?

Comment: A good starting point is the standard monograph on the topic, [Covering codes](https://www.elsevier.com/books/covering-codes/cohen/978-0-444-82511-7), from 1997.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_code) contains an entry on covering codes.

Answer (score 1):

So, according to **Theorem 4.3** of [this monograph by Réné Struik](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjOoqmTtqPsAhVQTBoKHbc-Ag8QFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpure.tue.nl%2Fws%2Ffiles%2F2274131%2F425174.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2QPc7-5EUmsCEaSHhzuxBh), if we consider $q$-ary binary codes of length $n$, such that $n \to \infty$ with $r/n \to p \in [0,(q-1)/q]$, then the minimal code size has the following asymptotic limit
$$
(1/n)\log_q N_{n,q}(r) \to 1-H_q(p),
$$
where $H_q(p)$ is the $q$-ary entropy of $p$. This answers my specific problem which corresponds to $q=2$.